# Import Maven project "YCSB" into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, ycsb

Can someone tell me the right way to import a Maven Project (in my case YCSB) into Eclipse Luna? 
I am trying it via `Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects`. Eclipse imports all the folders and files, but  there is an error in every folders POM.xml.

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:checkstyle (execution: validate, phase: validate)
```

Also I have no idea how to build and run the the project. I tried it by configuring a Maven Run Configuration with the goals `clean package` and compiled. The Build fails with following Console output.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.087 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-15T14:04:29+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/170M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Building the project with the commandline command `mvn clean package` builds the project without an error.

My system has Ubuntu 14.04 and Maven 3 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,
This error

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:checkstyle (execution: validate, phase: validate)
```

happend because you haven't the "Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in" installed in eclipse.
In eclipse menu:Help->install new software ,enter this site http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/update search `checkstyle` and install this plugin,the error in your pol.xml will all disapear.

Second,this error

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org:
 Der Name oder der Dienst ist nicht bekannt-> [Help 1]
```

indicates that your internet connection is broken and maven can not download the dependent jar file for compiling. Check you internet connection or configure a proxy for maven.
When the above is down, use `mvn clean package` to compile maven.You can also use `mvn -pl com.yahoo.ycsb:mongodb-binding -am clean package`to compile a certain database binding only.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is right way to import maven project in eclipse but you got some errors. please check error on error window(window->show view
->General->error log) then you get actual error.

Comment: The error log says.
`Provisioning exception
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases-forindigo/1.4/.`
I tried to compile again and now the project was successfully built. I guess my internet connection was broken. But I still have the errors in every folders POM.xml.
How do I now run the project? Can I build a Runnable Jar?

Comment: first use maven clean then use maven build